# returning object instead of array of object

Tags: python-3.x

I have an array of objects:

```
class row:
def __init__(self, name, value):
    self.name = name
    self.value = value
    
def __iter__(self):
   ''' Returns the Iterator object '''
   return TeamIterator(self)

rows.append(row('key1', 0.05))
rows.append(row('key2', 0.01))
```

when I do:

```
[{item.name:item.value} for item in rows]
[{'key1': 0.05}, {'key2': 0.01}]
```

instead I would like the result to be:

```
[{'key1': 0.05, 'key2': 0.01}]
```

any help is appreciated, thanks.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a line wrong.  Use:

```
[{item.name:item.value for item in rows}]
```

Instead of `[{item.name:item.value} for item in rows]`.